# How can i subtract all previous rows value from current rows value in teradata?

Tags: teradata

How can i subtract all previous rows value from current rows value in teradata? column Value is not in integer format.

Comment: How do you define "previous rows"? What format/data type is that column?

Answer (score 0):

You should learn Teradata OLAP Functions..and try below:-

```
select  COL1,COL2 , 
  coalesce(min(col2) over (partition by col1  order by col2 rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding), 0) as prv_value
col2-prv_value as diff
  from  TEMP
```